# Lost imei of zenfone max sd615

Tags: imei

I recently rooted my zenfone max(z010d) sd615 model and installed AIM ROM(custom rom) and due to some features that i felt missing in the rom i tried to revert back to stock and while returning to stock something strange happened and the mobile got switched off and hasn'nt turned on ,and searched many forums and finally managed to turn on by flash a firmware using asus flash tool but the mobile went into factory mode and no mobile signals at all and i've checked the imei it shows as '0'.tried may methods on web but cant solve imei problem. I hope this forum may help to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have the original flashable rom ? and is it a Mediatek SoC ?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is original or not but I've found a raw rom in firmware27.net for my device model

Comment: Send the link of the firmware downloaded from firmware27.net

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1inSC93FpC3sfgNhpJgXMD5QzDLpKEK4d/view